# how to display the which was inserted recently in to table

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I have a table in MySQL test_info . This table gets an insert command at random times such that a new record is added. This insert can be fired from anywhere.

Actually what have to do is?

front end should display the data which was inserted into the table recently in a real-time fashion.

please suggest me how solve this problem

Comment: you can use a field for saving time of creation. set default current timestamp. after fetvhing you can compare it and do waht you want.

Comment: could u write query?

Comment: what query to write?

Answer (score 1):

You would use `$mysqli->insert_id` to retrieve the id that was auto generated and used by the last query. Check it out [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php).

**Edit:** Based on Thorsten Kettner's comment, you could also use `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` which to my understanding isn't based on the current connection and instead is referenced globally.

You could even use `SELECT MAX(ID)` to get the last ID within a table, which most likely would be the most recent if set to `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Comment: This is the best way to do it.

Comment: Isn't this the last ID generated from this connection only? So you wouldn't get the last inserted record, because "This insert can be fired from anywhere". So far my understanding.

Comment: Okay. I think that $mysqli->insert_id simply reads LAST_INSERT_ID(). So these should be the same. But `SELECT MAX(ID)` is a good way, provided of course the table has an auto-incremented ID at all.

Answer (score 0):

First, for your client side, check out the [Server-Sent-Events](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/).
Secondly, you need a mechanism to check for latest updated data at your server side

Comment: how to write random insert query.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand what do you mean by *random insert query*

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mysql query to get last records. In my example shows how to get last 10 records.

here is the example

> select * from table order by date DESC LIMIT 10

Answer (score 0):

insert_id has some restrictions and I'm not sure how you will differ inserts from deletes.
What I would do will be *on insert trigger in each table where you need to track the insert
(may be you will want to track on update and on delete as well)

[triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html)
.

what you probably need is a separated table - **historical_data_tab** which holds all the historical data triggered by any event which you want to track.

for mysql :

```
    USE `db_name`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` TRIGGER track_insert AFTER INSERT ON your_table 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
        insert into historical_data_tab 
values (new.ID, 'INSERT',NOW());     

END
```

pay attention to new.ID and NOW(). In case you don't need the original PK, just insert NULL in place of new.ID and any Auto Increment PK  will take care of the rest. NOW will populate **historical_data_tab** table with a timestamps of the time the event was triggered. INSERT should tell you what type of event it was.

Replace it according to the trigger you'r using.
you might want to keep data about any of the following events*
after delete, insert, update
or
before delete, insert, update

p.s. There are a lot of ways to do what you need. Don't go crazy with triggers and try catching front end events in the front end itself

Comment: Its in sql or mysql. i want to insert in mysql. ie am using php.

Comment: please reply ninjabber

Comment: the sample code is for mysql.
the method is universal

Comment: could you write the query in mysql. and also write the random insert query in mysql

Comment: that's a trigger, not a query.
and it is "in mysql"

Answer (score 0):

select * from your_table where ID = Max(ID)